# running PVWatts for module system not in Sandia DB (python library)

Tags: python, pvlib

I want to run the PVWatts model (concretely to get pvwatts_dc) on an Amerisolar 315 module which doesn't seem to appear. What I am trying to do is to replicate the steps in the manual, which only requires system DC size.

When I go into the power model, the formula says `g_poa_effective` must be already angle-of-incidence-loss corrected. How do I do this correction? I've thought about using the physical correction formula `pvlib.pvsystem.physicaliam(aoi)`, but is this the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use an incident angle modifier function such as `physicaliam` to calculate the AOI loss, apply the AOI loss to the in-plane direct component, then add the in-plane diffuse component.

Comment: Sounds good. I was going to use the SAPM aoi loss model, but I couldn't find the polynomial coefficient in the amerisolar's online specs.